# PHP variable value in ColdFusion file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have implemented a captcha on a ColdFusion page. I want the value of those PHP variable to validate the captcha submission by user. I am trying to do it by ajax in jQuery..but not getting any success. Here is the code:-

PHP Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$word_1 = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) 
{
    $word_1 .= chr(rand(97, 122));
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) 
{
    $word_2 .= chr(rand(97, 122));
}
$_SESSION['random_number'] = $word_1.' '.$word_2;
$dir = 'fonts/';
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(165, 50);
$font = "recaptchaFont.ttf";
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); 
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0,0, 709, 99, $white);
imagettftext ($image, 22, 0, 5, 30, $color, $dir.$font, $_SESSION['random_number']);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image); 
$var = $word_1;
//echo "http://ed-s2:81/iucn_assets/custom/rangers/reCaptcha/get_captcha.php?var=".$var;
$word_1 = $_POST['firstRanNo'];
?>
```

ColdFusion file code(in jQuery to fetch PHP variable):

```
function change_captcha()
 {
    document.getElementById('captcha').src="http://ed-s2:81/iucn_assets/custom/rangers/reCaptcha/get_captcha.php?rnd=" + Math.random();
            var getNo = random_no();
            var num= "abc";         
             function random_no(){           
                 var res="";
                 $.ajax
                 ({
                    type:"POST",
                    data:{"firstRanNo":num},
                    url:"http://ed-s2:81/iucn_assets/custom/rangers/reCaptcha/get_captcha.php",
                    async:false,
                    success:function(result){

                        alert(result);
                    }        
                 });     
             }
 } 
});
```

What may be the problem ?

Comment: where you return the value or echo the value to use in the ajax sucess?

Comment: Codes which I am using to fetch the variable value is inside the ColdFusion file, so I can't use echo or any PHP code in there..
That is the main challenge...that...I have to fetch the value of the variable, which has been defined in PHP file to ColdFusion file using jQuery...

Comment: http://ed-s2:81/iucn_assets/custom/rangers/reCaptcha/get_captcha.php  what about the get_captcha.php? is the get_captcha.php return anything

Comment: No..
I have pasted the full code of this file above. I have just declared the variable like $word_1 = $_POST['firstRanNo']; Is there anything more I have to do to fetch this variable through $.ajax in my coldfusion file ?

Comment: Please try with echo $word_1; in php and check what is come in alert

Comment: I am creating two random number and adding them on a picture (which I am using as captcha image in my ColdFusion page). So when I am trying echo $word_1; - it's giving the first value of the random number which has been generated...

Comment: then echo the combination of $word_1 and $word_2 and use it

Comment: It's giving both values. But I don't have to use it on PHP page but at that page where ajax is implemented..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of ColdFusion are you using? If its ColdFusion 8 or higher, why not use the built in captcha functionality of <cfimage> - http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/Images_11.html ?

Comment: I am using ColdFusion 8. I am not using your mentioned captcha functionality because on the the press of refresh button for captcha image, it refresh the full page not just the image part :)

Comment: Could you not make an AJAX request to a .cfm page with a captcha value?